C++ WebServer: EventHandler (LibEvent Wrapper) Part-4
I think I made a mistake trying to start from the simplest version and working forward. This time I will present the final version, get all the fixes from here and incorperat them into the code, then I can reverse engineer the steps to get there.
The Parts of the server are:

NisseServer: Part-5
EventHandler: Part-4
Store: Part-3
JobQueue: Part-2
Pynt: Part-1

This post deals only with EventHandler.
The EventHandlerLibEvent.h provides RIAA wrapper for LibEvent types that I need. The EventHandler uses LibEvent to set callbacks and handlers. There is a timer that updates the Store state and any events on a file descriptor cause jobs to be added to the JobQueue.
EventHandlerLibEvent.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_EVENT_HANDLER_LIBEVENT_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_EVENT_HANDLER_LIBEVENT_H

/*
 * Wrapper class to give LibEvent types proper RIAA characteristics.
 *
 * EventBase is not copyable or movable.    libEvent    event_base
 * Event     is moveable.                   libEvent    event
 */

#include "NisseConfig.h"
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <utility>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse
{

using LibEventEventBase     = ::event_base;
using LibEventEvent         = ::event;
using LibEventTimeOut       = ::timeval;

class EventHandler;
enum class EventType : short{Read = EV_READ, Write = EV_WRITE};


class Event;
class EventBase
{
    friend class Event;
    LibEventEventBase*      eventBase;
    public:
        EventBase()
            : eventBase(event_base_new())
        {}
        ~EventBase()
        {
            event_base_free(eventBase);
        }

        EventBase(EventBase const&)                 = delete;
        EventBase(EventBase&&)                      = delete;
        EventBase& operator=(EventBase const&)      = delete;
        EventBase& operator=(EventBase&&)           = delete;

        void run()
        {
            event_base_loop(eventBase, EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY);
        }
};

class Event
{
    LibEventEvent*          event;

    public:
        Event(EventBase& eventBase, EventHandler& eventHandler);
        Event(EventBase& eventBase, int fd, EventType type, EventHandler& eventHandler);

        Event()
            : event(nullptr)
        {}
        Event(Event&& move)
            : event(std::exchange(move.event, nullptr))
        {}
        Event& operator=(Event&& move)
        {
            event = std::exchange(move.event, nullptr);
            return *this;
        }
        ~Event()
        {
            if (event) {
                event_free(event);
            }
        }
        Event(Event const&)                         = delete;
        Event& operator=(Event const&)              = delete;

        void add()
        {
            event_add(event, nullptr);
        }
        void add(int microsecondsPause)
        {
            LibEventTimeOut timeout = {0, microsecondsPause};
            evtimer_add(event, &timeout);
        }
};


}

#endif

EventHandler.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_EVENT_HANDLER_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_EVENT_HANDLER_H

/*
 * A thin wrapper on libEvent to C++ it.
 *
 * When an socket listener is first created via add() we store all data in the Store object.
 * When this has been created it adds the `ReadEvent` to libEvent to listen for any data.
 *
 * When (if) a socket event is triggered we save a lambda on the JobQueue addJob() that will be
 * executed by a thread. The lambda restarts the CoRoutine which will either yield one of
 * three values.
 *
 * When the code yields one of three situations happens:
 *      * TaskYieldState::RestoreRead    We restore the read listener waiting for more data.
 *      * TaskYieldState::RestoreWrite   We restore the write listener waiting for space to write.
 *      * TaskYieldState::Remove         We destroy the socket and all associated data.
 *
 * Note: This data is never destroyed immediately because the code may be executing on any thread.
 *       Instead a request is queued on the `Store` object. The main thread will then be used
 *       to clean up data (See Store for details).
 */

#include "NisseConfig.h"
#include "NisseUtil.h"
#include "EventHandlerLibEvent.h"
#include "Store.h"

/*
 * C-Callback registered with LibEvent
 */
extern "C" void eventCallback(evutil_socket_t fd, short eventType, void* data);
extern "C" void controlTimerCallback(evutil_socket_t fd, short eventType, void* data);

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse
{

class JobQueue;
class Store;
struct StreamData;
struct ServerData;

class EventHandler
{
    static constexpr int controlTimerPause = 1000;  // microseconds between iterations.

    JobQueue&       jobQueue;
    Store&          store;
    EventBase       eventBase;
    Event           timer;

    public:
        EventHandler(JobQueue& jobQueue, Store& store);

        void run();
        void add(TAS::Server&& stream, ServerCreator&& creator, Pynt& pynt);
        void add(TAS::SocketStream&& stream, StreamCreator&& creator, Pynt& pynt);

    private:
        friend void ::eventCallback(evutil_socket_t fd, short eventType, void* data);
        void eventHandle(int fd, EventType type);

    private:
        friend void ::controlTimerCallback(evutil_socket_t fd, short eventType, void* data);
        void controlTimerAction();

    private:
        struct ApplyEvent
        {
            EventHandler&   handler;
            int             fd;
            EventType       type;
            ApplyEvent(EventHandler& handler, int fd, EventType type)
                : handler(handler)
                , fd(fd)
                , type(type)
            {}
            void operator()(ServerData& info) {handler.addJob(info.coRoutine, fd);}
            void operator()(StreamData& info) {if (handler.checkFileDescriptorOK(fd, type)) {handler.addJob(info.coRoutine, fd);}}

        };
        bool checkFileDescriptorOK(int fd, EventType type);
        void addJob(CoRoutine& work, int fd);
};

}

#endif

EventHandler.cpp
#include "EventHandler.h"
#include "NisseUtil.h"
#include "JobQueue.h"
#include "Store.h"

/*
 * C Callback functions.
 * Simply decide the data into EventHandler and call the C++ functions.
 */
void eventCallback(evutil_socket_t fd, short eventType, void* data)
{
    ThorsAnvil::Nisse::EventHandler&    eventHandler = *reinterpret_cast<ThorsAnvil::Nisse::EventHandler*>(data);
    eventHandler.eventHandle(fd, static_cast<ThorsAnvil::Nisse::EventType>(eventType));
}

void controlTimerCallback(evutil_socket_t, short, void* data)
{
    ThorsAnvil::Nisse::EventHandler&    eventHandler = *reinterpret_cast<ThorsAnvil::Nisse::EventHandler*>(data);
    eventHandler.controlTimerAction();
}

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse;

/*
 * EventLib wrapper. Set up C-Function callbacks
 */
Event::Event(EventBase& eventBase, int fd, EventType type, EventHandler& eventHandler)
    : event{event_new(eventBase.eventBase, fd, static_cast<short>(type), &eventCallback, &eventHandler)}
{}

Event::Event(EventBase& eventBase, EventHandler& eventHandler)
    : event{evtimer_new(eventBase.eventBase, controlTimerCallback, &eventHandler)}
{}

EventHandler::EventHandler(JobQueue& jobQueue, Store& store)
    : jobQueue(jobQueue)
    , store(store)
    , timer(eventBase, *this)
{
    timer.add(controlTimerPause);
}

void EventHandler::run()
{
    eventBase.run();
}

void EventHandler::add(TAS::Server&& server, ServerCreator&& serverCreator, Pynt& pynt)
{
    int fd = server.socketId();
    store.requestChange(StateUpdateCreateServer{fd,
                                                std::move(server),
                                                std::move(serverCreator),
                                                Event{eventBase, fd, EventType::Read, *this},
                                                pynt
                                               });
}

void EventHandler::add(TAS::SocketStream&& stream, StreamCreator&& streamCreator, Pynt& pynt)
{
    int fd = stream.getSocket().socketId();
    store.requestChange(StateUpdateCreateStream{fd,
                                                std::move(stream),
                                                std::move(streamCreator),
                                                Event{eventBase, fd, EventType::Read, *this},
                                                Event{eventBase, fd, EventType::Write, *this},
                                                pynt
                                               });
}

void EventHandler::eventHandle(int fd, EventType type)
{
    StoreData& info = store.getStoreData(fd);
    std::visit(ApplyEvent{*this, fd, type},  info);
    /* The std::visit ApplyEvent object to call checkFileDescriptorOK()/addJob() below */
}

bool EventHandler::checkFileDescriptorOK(int fd, EventType type)
{
    /*
     * This function detects if the socket has been closed at the other end.
     * If the other end of the socket was closed this will induce a read event.
     * But no data will be available.
     */
    if (type == EventType::Write) {
        return true;
    }
    char buffer;
    ssize_t result = recv(fd, &buffer, 1, MSG_PEEK);
    if (result == 0 || (result == -1 && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK))
    {
        // Remove a socket if the other end has been closed.
        std::cout << "Remove Socket\n";
        store.requestChange(StateUpdateRemove{fd});
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void EventHandler::addJob(CoRoutine& work, int fd)
{
    /*
     * Add a job to the task queue.
     * This calls the passed CoRoutine and then updates the state of the object.
     * Note: The update is done via requestChange() as it can be called by any thread.
     */
    jobQueue.addJob([&work, fd, &store = this->store]()
    {
        TaskYieldState task = TaskYieldState::Remove;
        if (work()) {
            task = work.get();
        }
        switch (task)
        {
            case TaskYieldState::Remove:
                store.requestChange(StateUpdateRemove{fd});
                break;
            case TaskYieldState::RestoreRead:
                store.requestChange(StateUpdateRestoreRead{fd});
                break;
            case TaskYieldState::RestoreWrite:
                store.requestChange(StateUpdateRestoreWrite{fd});
                break;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Callback function controlled by timer.
 * This is used to processes all pending changes.
 *
 * Thus all changes to state are done by the main thread.
 */
void EventHandler::controlTimerAction()
{
    // Update all the state information.
    store.processUpdateRequest();
    // Put the timer back.
    timer.add(controlTimerPause);
}

